# Problem with memory leak check tools in Linux

Tags: linux, memory-leak-detector

1) Is there also any memory leak tool called `Boehmgc`? How is that tool compared to others?

2) I have used `LeakTracer`, `mudflap` and `Valgrind`. But unfortunately LeakTracer has the disadvantage of memory hogging (pooling a lot of memory at start and then allocating it), so what are the alternatives?

Comment: "List of all Xs" isn't a great question.

Comment: @awoodland: May be great for developers, in helping to choose the appropriate tool, LeakTracer as we know hogs a lot of memory at start, so knowing alternates can be helpful.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason and similar discussions is my concern

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79835/does-list-of-something-and-why-questions-belong-to-so-and-if-not-then-where

Comment: @awoodland: Hmm..In that case, a tag created like `memory-leak-detector` should also be deleted. Because as far as you have a tag, you can surely ask questions related to that.

Comment: you can very easily ask "how does one implement a memory-leak-detector", or "why does this leak detector say I have a leak?" with that tag.

Comment: I think there's enough meat to the question you asked beyond the "list of X" thing though, particularly if you rephrased it to ask "What's the difference between garbage collection and leak detection". It's the "can you name *all* leak check tools" that doesn't quite fit IMHO.

Comment: @awoodland: ok, you have a point. But my question has 2 parts. First part "name X" and the next part about `Boehm GC`. Anways, let me try to rephrase first part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Boehm GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) is a garbage collector, similar to the garbage collection in Java. The other tools you mention are designed to *warn* you about leaks, such that you can take corrective action. Garbage collection is designed to find and recover no-longer used allocations, as the program runs. Example (from wikipedia page):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gc.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    GC_INIT();
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    {
        // GC_MALLOC instead of malloc
        int **p = GC_MALLOC(sizeof(int *));
        int *q = GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC(sizeof(int));

        assert(*p == 0);
        // GC_REALLOC instead of realloc
        *p = GC_REALLOC(q, 2 * sizeof(int));
        if (i % 100000 == 0)
            printf("Heap size = %zu\n", GC_get_heap_size());
    }

    // No free()

    return 0;
}
```

Personally there's something about using garbage collection in C or C++ that makes me quite uneasy. For C++ "[Smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)" are the way to go in my opinion in scenarios where ownership is unclear (although you might want to have a thing about *why* it's unclear in your design) and for help with exception safety (E.g. what the now deprecated [`std::auto_ptr`](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm) was designed for)

As for the leak detectors you can add:

- [ccmalloc](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/ccmalloc/)
- [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/)
- [NJAMD (Not just another memory debugger)](http://fscked.org/projects/njamd)
- [mpatrol](http://mpatrol.sourceforge.net/)
- [YAMD (yet another malloc debugger)](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~nate/yamd/)

To your list of Linux ones.

Related memory checking tools, but not leaks:

- [Electric fence](http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence)

Comment: Efectric Fence is memory overrun detection tool not memory leak.

Comment: @king - I thought it had leak tracking too?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It has only memory overrun detection, and underruns too `EF_PROTECT_BELOW`

Comment: @awoodland: Thanks, it was great !! Let me wait for some more replies, before i accept your answer.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, thanks. Although it is closed, but i got my needs fulfilled :)

Comment: @awoodland: You missed out mudflap :)